# Visibility of onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: android, android-view

The methods `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state)` are declared protected in the `View` class, while in some of its subclasses, like `TextView` or `ListView`, they are declared public. To save and restore the state of a `ListView` after a configuration change, I can directly use those methods, while I can't for other `View`s like `ScrollView`. Why those methods are not declared public in the `View` class? Am I supposed to call those methods directly from my `Activity`/`Fragment` or in some other way? To restore the state of a `ScrollView` I can use a custom subclass that change the visibility of those methods to public: is this the way to go?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {

    public MyScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        return super.onSaveInstanceState();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should never call those methods at all.  The framework will call them at the appropriate times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-`Why those methods are not declared public in the View class?`

That is because they are only used to contain View, remember that `ScrollView` is a subclass of `ViewGroup` which mainly used for storing other views.

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html):

```
A ViewGroup is a special view that can contain other views (called children.) 
The view group is the base class for layouts and views containers
```

-`To restore the state of a ScrollView I can use a custom subclass that change the visibility of those methods to public`

Yes you can but it is just a container there is nothing special to save and also you can post the position that it will just recompute it again

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSaveInstanceState()):

```
 For example, you will never store your current position on screen because that will be 
 computed again when a new instance of the view is placed in its view hierarchy.

Some examples of things you may store here: the current cursor position in a text view 
(but usually not the text itself since that is stored in a content provider or other 
persistent storage), the currently selected item in a list view.
```

Comment: Ok, so what is the right way to restore the scroll position of a `ScrollView` after a configuration change? Do I have to handle it manually with `getScrollX()`, `getScrollY()` and `scrollTo(...)`? In my opinion, each View class should have an "authomatic" way to save and restore its state.

Comment: @Manuel use you activity's onsaveinstance to save scrollviewposition. Maybe it will get saved, maybe not for scrollviews.